# How to find and save a string section in ruby on rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I need to find a section of a string that includes the substring `"print time:"` and save it with the time it displays after the colon on the database.

What I've used until now is the `downcase` helper and the `includes?` helper to start the search but I'm not sure how to actually execute a search inside the string.

How can I find the section of the string so that I can save it afterwards?

Comment: You know how there's `puts` there's also `gets` I recommend you google "ruby gets" and start there :)

Comment: The string is not the result of a user input, it is the output of rails running a console program via backticks. I am able to store the output as a string, now I require to find the relevant data inside that huge string.

Comment: Right so what you want is a sub-string function then... have you checked out the string functions? http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/String.html

Comment: @TarynEast this looks promising, allow me to check it in detail.

Comment: What is the format for the time? Is it the string representation of a `Time` object, seconds since the Epoch, seconds since midnight, "Noon" or what? Please clarify by editing your question. Perhaps give a small example, including the desired result.

Comment: It is the total duration of the print in seconds might have been useful to clarify it is a 3D Print, anyway the question has been successfully answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [regular expressions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/), which in Ruby can be written with the `/…/` syntax and matched against using [`String#match`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-match).

```rb
log = "username: jsmith\nprint time: 08:02:41\npower level: 9001"
print_time = log.match(/print time:\s*([^\n]+)\s*\n/)[1]
p print_time # => "08:02:41"
```

The regex `/print time:\s*([^\n]+?)\s*\n/` matches any text after “print time:”, on the same line, ignoring surrounding whitespace `\s*`, and saves it as the first capture group using the `()`. Then `[1]` selects the contents of that first capture group.

After extracting the `print_time` string, you can do whatever you need to with it. For example, if you had a Rails model `PrintTime`, you might save the extracted time to the database with `PrintTime.create(extracted_time: print_time)`.

Comment: This look like it could solve my problem, how would it be written when the string is this: `print time: 4431`, the print time is actually in seconds.

Comment: @JorgeCuevas The regex I wrote will still work without changes. It just gets whatever is on the same line after “print time: ”, no matter its format. However, you will probably want to add a `.to_i` call to the result to convert it from a string to a number. Like `print_time_in_secs = log.match(…)[1].to_i`.

Comment: I noticed that it worked so I marked it as answered, and yes, the `.to_i` method was necessary. Many thanks for your help, you saved me much time with this answer.